# Cannot execute jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension I have included jquery.min.js in manifest file like this http://codepaste.net/ve31sq

But I can't seem to execute this code part in background.js

```
function getNparse() {
    jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Alert Dialog');
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: no that's the worse part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A background page never gets any content scripts injected. It's not an `http://` page to begin with, but even then it's not possible to specify a match pattern for it.

If you need jQuery there (along with plugins), you need to list it as a background script:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "jAlert-v2.js", "background.js"]
  },
```

Do note: the background page is invisible. Showing a custom alert on it won't help you anyhow. Looks like you're confised about how extensions work; start with the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Also, you should learn to [debug the background page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP0nMv_NI1s).

Comment: Then how do I link my functions to contentscript.js. Now my extension works like this: 1) popup.html (button pressed) 2) popup.js (added eventListener, and forwarded to background.js via chrome.extension.sendMessage). Here I want to make modifications on the web page I'm looking (like alerts, parsing tables, change values or add html to the document).

Comment: Read the overview I linked; it's covered there. You'll need a content script and Messaging between it and other parts.